# Data Recovery: Override kernel / usb-storage / sg idea of disk geometry

Tags: data-recovery, usb-storage

I have two Western Digital Caviar 68AA (6,8GB) drives pulled from an old server, one of them spun up and worked fine, and I retrieved the data using a USB-IDE converter.

The other drive did not spin, so I swapped the PCBs
This drive now spins up with the working PCB, but whereas the first drive displays:

```
[  826.126080] scsi 20:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD68 AA-32BAA0             PQ: 0    ANSI: 2
[  826.126966] sd 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  826.129050] sd 20:0:0:0: [sdc] 13305600 512-byte logical blocks: (6.81 GB/6.34 GiB)
```

this one is giving:

```
[  285.043143] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD10 2AA-00BAA0            PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  285.044484] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  285.058721] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] 20044080 512-byte logical blocks: (10.2 GB/9.55 GiB)
```

followed (understandably) by plenty of:

```
[ 2093.220784] sd 54:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 2093.220790] sd 54:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
```

This is not the first time I've swapped the controller on the same model of drive in an attempt to retrieve data, and it does usually work. 
These two drives were bought in a batch, the serial numbers are similar, however inspection of the controller boards reveals one chip being different.

Anyway, the question is, is there a way that I can try telling the usb-storage or scsi or sg driver, not sure which, to FORCE the geometry to 13200/16/63? I remember passing geometry for IDE drives to the kernel many years ago.
Maybe this is something at drive level that I cannot modify from the kernel?

Maybe the platter is damaged, or maybe there's some other problem. If I can't get the data, it's not critical, but I am wondering why the same controller board is reporting different sizes with identical drive casings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(My emphasis)

> inspection of the controller boards reveals **one chip being different**

Then later:

> I am wondering why **the same controller board** is reporting different sizes with **identical drive casings.**

The answer is quite simple: **those aren't the same circuit boards.** Hence, one isn't a drop-in replacement for the other.

That the drive model and serial numbers are similar *doesn't matter;* what matters is the exact hardware pairing. The manufacturer is fully within its rights to completely swap out the PCB in the middle of manufacturing, as long as the drive still adheres to the relevant attachment interface standard (very likely UDMA PATA in your case). Also, buying drives together increases the odds that they are from the same manufacturing batch; it does not guarantee that they are.

For a hard disk PCB transplant to be successful, the drives normally first off must be *identical* models. This is clearly not the case as there are visible differences in the circuitry involved. Second, it is usually recommended (though not *necessarily* required) that the drives run the same firmware code (same firmware, same version).

So, sorry. The drives that you have are not compatible with each other on the level required.

Comment: good answer, yes one board is a 
60-600843-001 REV A 
and the other is a 
60-600843-001 REV B

Comment: however, the differing chip is only the RAM, everything else looks the same, but of course, isn't. I guess something is programmed differently (firmware), so I'm still wondering if I can override this somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: @Keith "only the RAM"... that is a somewhat fundamental difference which means that the firmware is likely board specific as well.  You would not be able to simply copy the firmware from one board to another to "fix" this either and as there is likely to be some fundamental differences there too.  As Michael states you need *exactly* identical boards and *exactly* identical firmwares, and even then there might be some extra data in the firmware of one drive (i.e. calibration data) that makes it entirely incompatible with another drive.

Comment: Well yep.. the RAM seems to be different sizes based on datasheets I can find, but I disagree.. the brand of ram does not fundamentally change anything. 
I was lucky before, similar boards worked for me, but in this case I'm out of luck :(

Comment: @Keith Exactly. You were *lucky* before. HDD PCB transplants are one of those things that may or may not work, depending on a lot of specifics.

Comment: Leaving the dead board power powered up for a while, it started to try to spin up. I noticed a lot of heat around the L6262 (pre-amp?) 
Any chance powering the motor from the good board while connecting the original board to the data header might work?